# How to create expresssion tree with Any() method on ICollection property?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

Im trying to create expression tree to change predicate dynamically ,
I have an entity like below

### product

CatalogNo(pk)

VendorId

ProductToVendor(collection / Navigation property)

I have created expression tree as below

```
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> finalExpression = null;
List<Expression> expressionList = new List<Expression>();
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "p");

//Create predicate using expression tree
foreach (var keycolumn in request.KeyColumns)
{
    expressionList.Add(Expression.Equal(
                        Expression.Property(parameter, keycolumn.ColumnName),
                        Expression.Constant(keycolumn.ColumnValue, typeof(string))
                      ));
}

expressionList.Add(Expression.Equal(
              Expression.Property(parameter, "SiteId"),
              Expression.Constant(request.SiteId, typeof(int))
           ));
```

I want predicated to be like this

```
var vf = Context.Set<Product>().Where(p => p._ProductToVendor.Any(v => v.VendorId == VendorId) && p.SiteId == SiteId && p.CatalogNumber == catalogNo).ToList();
```

I have tried 
[Stack Overflow | Expression tree for child collection List.Any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748478/expression-tree-for-child-collection-liststring-any)

but i cant manage to get expected result ,
Can anyone help !

Comment: Have a look at http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically build and return a linq predicate based on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932542/how-to-dynamically-build-and-return-a-linq-predicate-based-on-user-input)

Comment: But it uses pedicate builder ,

Comment: If you need to create a predicate using the name of the fields in strings try this one... 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256640/expression-predicates-with-field-name-as-parameter

Comment: Your question is quite incomplete, and I feel pieces are missing. I don't see anywhere `_ProductToVendor`. It isn't clear if `request.KeyColumns` should be the columns *inside* the `.Any()` or *outside* (the `CatalogNumber` is missing in your code). The `typeof(string)` smells bad... Are all your columns `string`s?